# Fastest Dictionary lookup in c# .net Compact Framework 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, compact-framework, lookup

I'm looking for the fastest way to lookup if List, Set, Dictionary contains a specific Keyword (string). I don't need to store any data inside I just want to know if my Keyword is in the List.

I thought about some possibilities like:

```
Dictionary<string, bool> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
if (myDictionary.ContainsKey(valueToSearch))
{
    // do something
}
```

but I don't need a value.

```
string[] myArray = {"key1", "key2", "key3"}
if (Array.IndexOf(myArray, valueToSearch) != -1)
{
    // do something
}
```

Then I found:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
if (list.Contains(valueToSearch))    
{
    // do something
}
```

The lookup will happen very often and has to be very fast.
Any idea what's the fastest way to check if a value equals one of a given list of keys?

Comment: Why dont you get a copy of RedGate Profiler and run some tests yourself? It will give you a good indication of what will be faster for look up. some things will affect the performance such as order of the items and algorithm used and size of the list. I was going to do it but my trial expired http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/

Comment: Which data structure is fastest is usually strongly linked to the size of the problem, the redundancy of the data, the distribution of queries, and the likelihood of a "junk" (that is, not matching) query. The problems we face in making a compiler local variable lookup table fast are *completely* different than the problems you face in making a Scrabble dictionary lookup fast. Local variable tables are small and queries tend to cluster; Scrabble dictionaries are large and queries seldom repeat. Can you describe the characteristics of the problem in more detail?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of the standard collection types, `Dictionary` will be the fastest, since I don't think you have `HashSet<T>` in the compact framework. The other two do a sequential search.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm interpreting MSDN correctly, but it looks like HashSet<T> is included in the compact framework. [HashSet<T> documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=VS.100).aspx)

Comment: @Justin: HashSet is not available in the CF.

Comment: @ctacke - Ah, I see now -- I read "client profile" on MSDN and thought "compact framework".

Comment: @Justin - yeah MSDN is rarely what I'd call "clear" for CF support.

Answer (score 3):

In general, a Dictionary lookup is the usual solution to a problem like this, as long as your keys are good hash values that get a somewhat even distribution in the dictionary's lookup table.

However, there may be certain cases where a list lookup appears to run faster, depending on how the data is sorted and what exactly you are looking up.

The best way to tell is to run a profile of each case, and see which performs better.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Andy. You could also look at SortedList It's essentially a Dictionary that's sorted by its keys. Should make searching quicker if it's already sorted...

Comment: Sorting the items won't increase the speed of lookup, since `SortedDictionary` still uses a hash table for lookup. Hash table lookup is an O(1) operation. Searching in a sorted list is typically an O(log n) operation. The only time searching is going to outperform a hash lookup is if the hash table has an overabundance of collisions (meaning that either the hashing function is inadequate or the table is almost full).